# creating gmail accounts with python

Tags: python, api, gmail

I am trying to create a gmail account with python using an article I found on medium. Here's the article: https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-temporary-gmails-accounts-with-python-9c200c52ebb7

Here is my code:

```
def generate_gmail(ID: int):
  
  # access the API
  url = "https://temp-gmail.p.rapidapi.com/get"
  querystring = {"id":ID,"type":"alias"}
  headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "temp-gmail.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "YOUR PRIVATE KEY"
    }
  
  # send a request to the API
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
  
  # convert the response to JSON format 
  json_response = response.json()
  # get gmail address
  gmail = json_response['items']['username']
  # get gmail password
  password = json_response['items']['key']

  print('Gmail address: %s' % str(gmail))
  print('Password: %s' % str(password))
```

I have inputted my private key. When I run the code with "python3 file_name.py" in terminal I do not receive an output of an email and password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code only defines a function but doesn't call it.

Comment: Are you sure that you follow that article step by step? did you call generate_gmail(ID=YOUR_ID) somewhere in your "file_name.py"?

Answer (score 0):

Add `print(json_response['message'])`

If you get message "You are not subscribed to this API." then you have not subscribed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to call the function
Add this line to your code

generate_gmail(ID:3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).